# Switch from KDialog to Zenity

Tags: debian, kde, kde-4, desktop-customization, zenity

I'm using KDE 4.8.4. Is it possible to cease to use KDialog in KDE and switch to Zenity permanently?

KDialog is driving me crazy. It always freezes everywhere at save and open dialogs, in Google chrome, in Okular... I can't continue with it!

Thanks.

Comment: At least say it's impossible...

Answer (score 0):

Zenity is GTK only so it is not a practical option in KDE unless you dont care about having GTK3 installed as well.

I am actually looking for an alternative to Zenity in KDE but so far I can't find the solution...the closest I have found is Kommander. - http://www.kde.org/applications/development/kommander/

There is so little information about Kommander though so who knows whether it could solve it or not.